# Is there a special hyphen-symbol to be used between capital letters?

Tags: punctuation, typography, hyphenation, capitalization

In words consisting of small letters, the `-` hyphen seems right. In words (abbreviations, acronyms) consisting of capital letters, the common hyphen appears (at least imho) to be placed too low and to be too short (and en-dash too long). Is there a "capital-letter-hyphen-command"? (And what to use as hyphen between small and capital letters?) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
pole-axe versus CD-ROM versus FamouseMusicGroup-CD versus A-side
\end{document}
```

At least the hyphen in `CD-ROM` looks "wrong" to me.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\capitalhyphen}{\raisebox{0.24ex}{\resizebox{0.4em}{\height}{-}}\kern-0.07em}
```

would be possible, but I assume that there is already a solution to this, isn't it?

[image: hyphens]

top line: `-`

bottom line: `\capitalhyphen`

- pole-axe `-` is OK
- CD-ROM   needs `\capitalhyphen` (or the command to use in this case)
- FamouseMusicGroup-CD neither `-` nor `\capitalhyphen` seem to be ideal, but `-` is acceptable
- A-side   `-` is OK

Comment: I would say the typographically correct thing would be to use small caps for all-capital letter words.

Comment: @Jake: As `\textsc{CD-ROM}` generates the same output as `CD-ROM`, I assume that you propose to use `\textsc{cd-rom}`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's also what [Erik Spiekerman would do](http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/typo_tips.pdf).

Comment: @Jake: In that case the normal hyphen `-` is fine, of course. I'll have to think about using `\textsc`, but would still be interested to know whether there is some "capital hyphen". (And using `\textsc{abc-de} Inc.` might not be an option if ABC-DE Inc. must approve the text and would prefer `\Huge` anyway...) Thanks for the link!

Comment: I know it doesn't address your question, but in the three cases you show I would not hyphenate at all, except in narrow columns.

Comment: @Marco: At least in [CD-ROM](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cd%20rom) and [A-list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20list) the hyphen is part of the word and not introduced by line-breaking, so it's not really a matter of choice.

Comment: In my opinion, the negative effect of hyphens "jumping" vertically between different words is worse than that of hyphens slightly misplaced for capitalised words.

Comment: @Jake: Another possibility is also `{\large\textsc{cd-rom}}`, which is between `CD-ROM` and `\textsc{cd-rom}`. And with `\textsc`the hyphen is placed "right" (i.e. as I would like to see it printed). Could you turn your comments into an answer, please?

Comment: @Marco: Yes, I did not want to break the words but write them with a hyphen, but I'm no native speaker. Those words were just examples anyway.

Comment: Now see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103308/uneven-spacing-around-a-hyphen-in-sans-serif

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say the typographically correct thing would be to use small caps for all-capital letter words, for example `CD-ROM` would become `\textsc{cd-rom}`:

[image]

That way, the hyphen is aligned nicely with the surrounding letters, and the all-caps word doesn't stand out as much. This is also the solution suggested by Erik Spiekerman in his [Typo Tips](http://www.fontshop.com/education/pdf/typo_tips.pdf).

Comment: What would you do in case of hyphenated initials, as in `J.-M. Doe`?

Comment: @tohecz: They would be typeset in normal capitals

Comment: @Jake And you would use normal hyphen? (That's where my question aimed to.)

Comment: @tohecz: Yes, exactly

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that it needs to be longer than the normal size. Consider the following:

[image]

As you will observe the  hyphen is as wide as one of the narrow letters. However, if you still looking to have it a bit wider you can consider to pick it up from a different font (the width varies with fonts) or select it from a larger size. (Image from wikipedia).

[image]

But perhaps the best advice is to use small caps as noted by Jake in the comments.

Comment: The length was just a secondary issue indeed. I just suspected that there would be a command/package/whatsoever for this, thus I mentioned it. Small caps is also my favourite. Thanks for the example! +1

Answer (score 2):

Vertical alignment of rules is always a difficult matter in typography. Looking at this,

[image: Beast]

you might feel the horizontal strokes of B and e are not properly aligned. Rotis has a (radically?) different approach:
[image: Rotis]

But it's really a matter of taste.

In my opinion, the negative effect of hyphens "jumping" vertically between different words is worse than that of hyphens looking slightly vertically misplaced for capitals.

Comment: The `-` is about aligned with the `e` in Beast, therefore in `B-F` it appears too low. Of course this is just a matter of taste. I checked a programme of someone from Redmond, but it is probably without significance that it uses the same hyphens between capital and small letters.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if I understand your question the right way, but why don't you use the `--` command as hyphen between words.

There are three types of hyphen

- `-` to split words
- `--` to combine different words, e.g. CD-ROM
- `---` to seperate two sentences from each other

Here is a short example in the same order:

[image: Three different hyphens]

Comment: I don't think the use of the en-dash (`--`) to combine different words is correct (or customary, as there's really no wrong or right in typography). The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.educause.edu%2Felements%2Fattachments%2Feducause%2Fpdf%2Fch07_tab01.pdf&ei=eWd9T5XLGoWcOtrzzKkM&usg=AFQjCNHNwySicZ1lNANDNfD-jnU0yDRXKg&sig2=gxpiJTnS2AhTCQF1RJRAaQ) suggests using en-dashes in compounds only if it joins a prefix with an "open compound" (so `ex-girlfriend` but `ex--corporate executive`).

Comment: I think (as it _is_ just a matter of taste) that `--` is too long, and it does not solve the issue that it is (for my taste) too low. But thanks for mentioning it!